# How to get Google Calendar updates each day - OUTDATED

Tags: node.js, discord, google-calendar-api, discord.js

Update: I successfully got it to post events between two dates. The problem is I set the two dates to year-month-dayT00:00:00.000Z and year-month-dayT23:59:59.999Z. but it sends events from the previous day and the day I set it to. See code snippets after everything else.

Original:
I use discord a lot in communications and now I am part of a robotics team that would like to use it as well. The only problem is, it doesn't work with Google calendar. So I looked around a bit to see if i could find a bot that i could use. There are a few out there but non of them are that great. So I decided to make my own. I am using node.js and the google calendar api.

So far I have gotten the authentication of the calendar down so that works. But now I am trying to figure out how to get daily updates in a discord channel. This is the default example Google gives you on doing this. Only problem is all it does is just give the next 10 events on your calendar, not just for the day.

if anyone could help me figure out how to go about doing this it would be much apreciated.

```js
function getEvents(auth) {
  var calendar = google.calendar('v3');
  calendar.events.list({
    auth: auth,
    calendarId: 'primary',
    timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
    maxResults: 10,
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime'
  }, , function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    var events = response.items;
    if (events.length == 0) {
      console.log('No upcoming events found.');
    } else {
      console.log('Upcoming 10 events:');
      for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        var event = events[i];
        var start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
        console.log('%s - %s', start, event.summary);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Here is what I have to run it everyday:

```js
var datetime = new Date();

datetime.getHours('newlistener', (event, addEventListener) => {
  if (datetime.getHours == 24) {
    getEventsForDay();
  }
  else {
    return;
  }
});
```

Updated code:

```js
var datetime = new Date();

function getCurrentDayList() {
  var year = ('0' + datetime.getUTCFullYear()).slice(-4);
  var month = ('0' + (datetime.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
  var day = ('0' + (datetime.getUTCDate())).slice(-2);

  return (year + '-' + month + '-' + day + 'T00:00:00.000Z');
}

function getNextDayList() {
  var year = ('0' + datetime.getUTCFullYear()).slice(-4);
  var month = ('0' + (datetime.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
  var day = ('0' + (datetime.getUTCDate())).slice(-2);

  return (year + '-' + month + '-' + day + 'T23:59:59.999Z');
}

function listEvents(auth) {
  var calendar = google.calendar('v3');
  calendar.events.list({
    auth: auth,
    calendarId: 'primary',
    timeMin: getCurrentDayList(),
    timeMax: getNextDayList(),
    maxResults: 10,
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime'
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    var events = response.items;
    if (events.length == 0) {
      console.log('No upcoming events found.');
    } else {
      console.log('Upcoming 10 events:');
      for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        var event = events[i];
        var start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
        console.log('%s - %s', start, event.summary);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `timeMax` and `timeMin`.

**timeMax**

> - Upper bound (exclusive) for an event's start time to filter by. Optional. The default is not to filter by start time. Must be an RFC3339 timestamp with mandatory time zone offset, e.g., 2011-06-03T10:00:00-07:00, 2011-06-03T10:00:00Z. Milliseconds may be provided but will be ignored. If timeMin is set, timeMax must be greater than timeMin.

**TimeMin**

> - Lower bound (inclusive) for an event's end time to filter by. Optional. The default is not to filter by end time. Must be an RFC3339 timestamp with mandatory time zone offset, e.g., 2011-06-03T10:00:00-07:00, 2011-06-03T10:00:00Z. Milliseconds may be provided but will be ignored. If timeMax is set, timeMin must be smaller than timeMax.

timeMax 2018-01-06T00:00:00-08:00

timeMin 2018-01-05T00:00:00-08:00

Also there is a [tutorial](http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2010/06/07/howto-google-calendar-api-php-retrieve-events-part-2/) on "Retrieve events occuring between a date range."

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have not had a chance to see if this works as I ended up abandoning the project as it was no longer needed. However, I will definitely refer back to this if I try the same thing again.